# Can someone clear up my confusion regarding who vs. whom?

Tags: word-choice, whom

Specifically, in this sentence:

> … of the people who suffered early trauma, there were some whom it affected in such a way that they …

(I've mercifully only included part of the sentence)

I can't seem to figure out if it should be *who* or *whom*. I understand the whole 'subject/object' concept, but that does not seem to clarify what is correct in this particular sentence. Professor Google seems to not know, either.

All I know is *whom* sounds terribly incorrect here, even if it is correct.

Comment: "Who" acts, and the action is received by "whom".

Comment: 60 years ago at grammar school, 'who' would have been marked wrong in your example (it affected them, not they ... objective case). But nowadays, 90+% of practised speakers would use 'who' as the near-universal replacement for 'whom' (and many of them would be sensible and use it in print too).

Comment: The easy way - just decide whether it's Q: ***Who** suffered?* A: ***He** suffered* (nominative, someone ***did*** something) OR Q: ***Whom** did it affect?* A: *It affected **him*** (objective, something ***happened to*** someone). The ***really*** easy way - just forget about ***whom*** completely, and use ***who*** everywhere.

Comment: You say it "sounds terribly incorrect", which is a native speaker judgement. Are you a native speaker? If so, it's worth mentioning in your question, because most questions here are not from natives and there are different standards of "correct" involved.

Comment: If you are somebody who uses _whom_, and in a context where you might use _whom_, then _whom_ is what you want here, as it is the object of _it affected_. Simples. If both of those conditions do not hold, then use _who_.

Comment: Yes, sir, Mr. Lawler. Born and raised in the midwest, urban all my life, full education, good vocabulary, and have written 5 novels.The substitution of he/she or her/him seems to not work for this sentence, because the 'whom' being referred to are not defined, they are only 'possible'. It's speculative. I'm not convinced that 'whom it affected' is an object—that can be considered a subjective noun phrase, too.

Comment: Who said that "whom it affected" is an object? Syntactically, the pronoun is object of "affected" in the relative clause, so trad grammar has it that "whom" is correct. You know the rest of the story.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   We were taught the 'm' rule - whom did it affect? Him.

Comment: Possibly it's confusing when the object comes before the subject. 'Who am I?' is correct, bc it is a reversal of 'I am who?', which is a syntactical variant of the same exact thought. The subject is still 'I' in either case. That's why 'Who am me?' does not work—I is the subject, even though it comes after the object.

Comment: @Thomas What object? There's no object in "Who am I?" "Who" is predicative complement of "be". Note that objects only occur with transitive verbs, not with intransitive ones like copula "be".